How to optimize BufferedReader reading?
I have a code written in Java that shows all installed programs on a PC. But for some reason after this line, the program runs 25 seconds longer than usual.
sb.append(reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
The code itself:
class InstalledPrograms {
    public static String getPrograms() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(getCommand().split(" "));
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            sb.append(reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }


    private static String getCommand() {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        if (os.contains("window"))
            return "wmic product get name,version";
        if (os.contains("linux"))
            return "dpkg --list";
        return "pkgutil --pkgs"; // for MacOS
    }
}

I tried to use ProcessBuilder - it didn't help. I tried to use toString() to avoid going through each element - it didn't help either.

How long does dpkg --list (or whichever command you use for your os) need without the java-wrapper?

Ah, now I understand why my program is taking so long to run. Do you know how to get a list of all programs faster?

sudo dpkg --get-selections should take tens of milliseconds if you have sudo configured correctly.  Pointless really splitting the output by lines only to join it all with newline characters again

    public static String getPrograms() {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(getCommand().split(" "));
            Process process = processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            reader.transferTo(sw);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sw.toString();
    }

Command:

 time java InstalledPrograms

Output:

a2ps                                            install
aapt                                            install
accountsservice                                 install
acl                                             install
acpi                                            install
acpi-fakekey                                    install
...
zathura                     install
zathura-pdf-poppler             install
zenity                      install
zenity-common                   install
zip                     install
zlib1g:amd64                    install
zlib1g:i386                 install
zlib1g-dev:amd64                install
zoom                        install
zsh                     install
zsh-common                  install


real    0m0.228s
user    0m0.286s
sys 0m0.086s

